# syntax error: identifier 'DXGI_RGBA in file dxgi1_2.h

Tags: syntax, directx, toolkit

Trying to integrate the Directx toolkit into my game. I followed the steps here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Adding-the-DirectX-Tool-Kit

and everything went great. When trying to include one of the headers (SpriteFont.h) I get these errors[image]:

I've refactored the project to 8.1 to match my game, and rebuilt the imported project and it works great. It's when rebuilding my project that I get these error.

(I've already made sure windows.h is being included before my directx headers.

Help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More than likely you are mixing the legacy DirectX SDK headers with the Windows 8.x SDK headers and mixing the old DXGI headers with new ones. As detailed on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx), if you want to mix the old DirectX SDK with the Windows 8.x SDK, you need to invert the traditional include path order.

Don't use this:

```
<IncludePath>$(DXSDK_DIR)Include$(IncludePath);</IncludePath>
<LibraryPath>$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86$(LibraryPath);</LibraryPath>
<LibraryPath>$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x64;$(LibraryPath);</LibraryPath>
```

Use this:

```
<IncludePath>$(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include</IncludePath>
<LibraryPath>$(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86</LibraryPath>
<LibraryPath>$(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x64;</LibraryPath>
```

There are also some `#include` tricks if you are using older stuff like `D3DX` headers which can implicitly pick up the old headers.

Ideally you should remove all use of the legacy DirectX SDK paths, but if you want to use XAudio on Windows 7 you need to continue to use it. See the [wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Audio) for details.

Comment: Hello ! I have exactly the same error as Scrumble. I did exaclty as you said in your answer but still the error stays. I've been including <windows.h> before the dx headers too. My project was compiling (with direct x) until i started creating classes inheriting from some other classes, do you think that might be the reason of the error ? (i'm on Windows 10, 64 bit). This would be amazing if you could have some time to help ! Thank you :)

Comment: What classes are you 'inheriting' from?

Answer (score 0):

you can probably try to #include "SpriteFont.h" in your .cpp file instead of your .h header file.
I solved this problem in this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use legacy DirectX SDK and newer Visual studio version(like vs2015 or vs2017 or vs2019). I recommend you read this [link from book official site](http://www.d3dcoder.net/Data/Book4/d3d11Win10.htm). I think the official site miss something:

1. For every code sample you compile make sure

   $(DXSDK_DIR)\Utilities\bin\x86; before $(ExecutablePath);

   ....\Common;$(DXSDK_DIR)\Include; before $(IncludePath)

   $(DXSDK_DIR)\Lib\x86;....\Common;$(VC_LibraryPath_x86);  before $(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86)

[image]
when you build Effects framework you should also guarantee this order.

2. [Copy the files: d3dx11effect.h, Effects11d.lib and Effects11.lib into
   the book’s Common directory (overwriting the old ones).](http://www.d3dcoder.net/Data/Book4/d3d11Win10.htm).

After you copy d3dx11effect.h to Common directory you need to change one line like this:
[image: I think this could help @Scumble373]

3. If you come cross this error

> dxerr.lib(dxerrw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __vsnwprintf referenced in function "long __stdcall StringVPrintfWorkerW(unsigned short *,unsigned int,unsigned int *,unsigned short const *,char *)" (?StringVPrintfWorkerW@@YGJPAGIPAIPBGPAD@Z)

you could add legacy_stdio_definitions.lib; like this:
[image] without needing to [add dxerr.h and dxerr.cpp to book’s Common directory and add these two files to your project](http://www.d3dcoder.net/Data/Book4/d3d11Win10.htm)
and dxerr.h and dxerr.cpp are now [here](https://walbourn.github.io/wheres-dxerr-lib/).

4. I commit my vs2019 buildable code [here](https://github.com/lili2012/Introduction-to-3D-Game-Programming-with-DirectX-11). It is chapter 1 and chapter 6 box demo buildable But I will build more chapter as I learn this book.

Feel free to comment here or the [github repo](https://github.com/lili2012/Introduction-to-3D-Game-Programming-with-DirectX-11)!