# How to compile a demo from "Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 11" in Visual Studio 2015 (or later version)?

Tags: directx, directx-11

I've been stuck with this for a few weeks and I just kept getting strange debug errors like:

1.a combination of 3 errors about DXGI_RGBA in dxgi1_2.h(now has temporary disappeared)
   C4430,C2143 and C2061
   like errors in this link
   [Errors about dxgi1_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174893/syntax-error-identifier-dxgi-rgba-in-file-dxgi1-2-h)
2.error C2677: binary '*': no global operator found which takes type 'DirectX::XMVECTOR' (or there is not acceptable converstion)
   This version of overload for operator* is declared in DirectXMath.h, defined in DirectXMathVector.inl and works perfectly fine in other parts of this demo project.
3.Sometimes lots of errors just pop up when I open a file but they won't be considered as errors when building.

I wonder if there is something to do with the include order I take.

Is it possible to give me a clear guide for how to deploy demos from this book in vs2015? I would truely appreciate that. Thanks!

Comment: The answer is already in the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174893/syntax-error-identifier-dxgi-rgba-in-file-dxgi1-2-h) you linked. The Frank Luna book uses the legacy DirectX SDK before it was integrated into the Windows 8.x SDK. VS 205 uses the Windows 8.x SDK by default. See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/04/07/book-recommendations/). Also, don't use both ``xnamath.h`` and ``DirectXMath.h``, just use ``DirectXMath.h``; see [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/03/26/introducing-directxmath/).

Comment: Sorry for this late reply and thanks a lot! :) I am now able to run those demos. A part of my problems were caused by not defining _XM_NO_INTRINSICS_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by including DirectXMath.h and adding

using namespace DirectX;

in the CPP file where I got that error.

All of the operators were moved into the DirectX namespace in the latest SDK